# Moving the margin on the ecv document class

Tags: europecv

I am trying to create my CV on the www.sharelatex.com website using the ecv (english) template. The inconvenience I see here is that the margin that separates the page is way too much on the right. In other words, I am looking to move the margin a little to the left so that there is more space on the right for the actual content to go in and consequently reduces the number of pages that the document comprises of which is really important when it comes to a CV. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you give u a link to the template? I bet you can use plain and easy `geometry` to alter the margins.

Comment: @Johannes_B, appreciate your quick response. Here's a link to the template https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/ecv-cur%C2%ADricu%C2%ADlum-vi%C2%ADtae-english-versioin

Comment: `geometry` is already loaded by the class; you can use `\geometry{margin=6cm,left=3mm}` to change the margins to your taste.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the margins you have to add this piece of code.

```
\documentclass[english]{ecv}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
  a4paper,
  total={210mm,297mm},
  left=20mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=20mm,
  bottom=20mm,
 }
```

You have to change the values of left, right, top and bottom as you want to modify the margins.

I hope that it helps you, good luck!